# Reference suggestions - Contemporary Western Philosophy

Tags: phenomenology, existentialism, logical-positivism

I want to read following topics

Moore,  Russell  and  Early  Wittgenstein:  Defence  of  Commonsense;  Refutation  of  Idealism;  Logical  Atomism;  Logical  Constructions;  Incomplete  Symbols;  Picture  Theory  of  Meaning;  Saying  and  Showing.

Logical  Positivism:  Verification  Theory  of  Meaning;  Rejection  of  Metaphysics;  Linguistic  Theory  of  Necessary  Propositions.

Later  Wittgenstein:  Meaning  and  Use;  Language-games;  Critique  of  Private  Language.

Phenomenology  (Husserl):  Method;  Theory  of  Essences;  Avoidance  of  Psychologism.

Existentialism (Kierkegaard,  Sartre, Heidegger): Existence and  Essence; Choice, Responsibility and  Authentic  Existence;  Being-in-the  –world  and  Temporality .

Quine  and  Strawson :  Critique  of  Empiricism;  Theory  of  Basic  Particulars  and  Persons.

Please suggest a standard reference for above topics.

Comment: You can see most of this "items" in *SEP*; e.g. [Logical Empiricism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-empiricism/) with good overview, bibliography and historical details. It is easy to search ...